# Append select value to URL

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I found these tips

```
<select id="title">
          <option value="1">Mr</option>
          <option value="2">Mrs</option>
          <option value="3">Miss</option>
        </select>
```

Now that the user has selected the 2nd option: Mrs. To get the value (in this case, ‘2’):

```
$("select#title").val();
```

This is all OK. What I want to do is append  **$("select#title").val();** to an URL like this one

```
 $.get('http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/select/2', function(data)
```

in place of 2
I tried `$.get('http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/select/ $("select#title").val()', function(data)`
but this it failed.
Any ideas plz?

```
<div id="teln_operatorbundle_centrextype">
<div>
<label class="required" for="teln_operatorbundle_centrextype_numberrange">Numberrange</label>
<select id="teln_operatorbundle_centrextype_numberrange" multiple="multiple" required="required" name="teln_operatorbundle_centrextype[numberrange][]">
<option value="2">060013000</option>
<option value="3">060014700</option>
</select>
</div>
<input id="teln_operatorbundle_centrextype__token" type="hidden" value="f239bb430b4153d5d88fc7234751039a73253e87" name="teln_operatorbundle_centrextype[_token]">
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.get('http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/select/' + $("select#title").val(), function(data)
```

Comment: not the desired answer. this what I get http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/select/%5Bobject%20Object%5D. Meanwhile I want it to be http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/select/2

Comment: @user2248882 did you remember to use `.val()`?

Comment: yes I did @wirey I can not understand where is the problem originated from

Comment: It works fine [http://jsfiddle.net/pnD9R/](http://jsfiddle.net/pnD9R/)

Comment: I'll join now my real example, which id should I enter in the select : #teln_operatorbundle_centrextype_numberrange or teln_operatorbundle_centrextype?  @SeanWM

Comment: thanks, I found about my error. It's not related to these issue.

Answer (score 3):

Otherwise Try this,

```
var title = $("select#title").val();

$.get('http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/select/'+title)
```

Comment: var title = $("#title :selected").val();

Comment: @exampleusername It will give the selected value only. Don't need to put :selected

Comment: Why wouldn't you want the selected value?

Comment: @exampleusername var title = $("select#title").val() this statement will give the selected value only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use string concatenation to form the URL from your two parts (the static string and your dynamic value):

```
$.get('http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/select/' + $('#title').val(), function(data) {

});
```